# Create AssistiveTouch-like UI in iOS (using private APIs)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, iphone-privateapi, assistive

I'm wondering if by using Apple's private API I would be able to run my app in the background and provide a pop-over UI like the [AssistiveTouch](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202658) feature does, which can be activated from any part of the OS.

My app wouldn't need to be distributed through the App Store, so I have some freedom to explore use of such private routes.